# How to calculate the right motor size for a soil sifter

Tags: motor, vibration-motor

**How would one calculate the proper size of an electric motor to properly drive a soil sifter?**

**Assumptions:**
**Screen:**  flat, 18"x24", 1/4" to 3/4" wire cloth (interchangeable screens), total weight (including frame) = 4 lbs
**Shake Info:** total screen movement/shake = 6", shake rate = 132 shakes per minute
**Load:**  15 lbs soil or gravel mix
**Other:** Belt driven

**Note:**  I'd hate to use a 3/4 hp motor when all I might need is a 1/50 hp motor.

Comment: I suspect a lot of people would start with whatever non-trivially-sized motor was on hand, and then redesign if necessary.  The 3/4 HP does sound like a better starting point if it is available, and it should not be a cost driver by the time you have built the whole machine.  For a typical 1750 RPM induction motor (or slightly slower in 50 Hz countries) you will probably need two stage belt reduction to get down to 132 RPM, a key question is if a continuous drive will give enough impulse or if you need to rig up some sort of trip/release kind of cam.

Comment: I'd expect this thing to "walk" in use unless it's either well ballasted or bolted down...

Comment: You can easily calculate the power required to accelerate (15+4lbs) over a 6 inch amplitude 132 times a minute. Choose a motor more powerful than that.

Comment: Perhaps an impact design instead of continuous shaking with motor? Or go with a rotating sifter design.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - the frame will be on rollers that ride in a channel that is mounted to a base stand--so it shouldn't 'walk'.  Would you elaborate on your comment about enough impulse/a trip/release cam?  Is that about whether or not the motor will have enough power to start with a load on it from a dead stop or some kind of shaker engage/disengage type of mechanism that you are referring to?

Comment: @Brian Drummond - Would you show the calculations that you referred to?  The power of the motor just has to be sufficient to move the screen & frame under the load--remember, the load is not moving back & forth--the screen is ripping at the based of the load shaking bits through it.

Comment: crasic - Would you please elaborate on the "impact design" that you referred to?  Also, fyi, I don't want a trommel design, so that suggestion isn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: Essentially what I am asking is if you put a linkage on a wheel rotating at 132 RPM, such that the screen moves sinusoidally with an amplitude of 6", will that be violent enough to accomplish your goal?  Or do you need the movement to be more abrupt than sinusoidal?  Admittedly, when I first read your post I was thinking a vertical movement.

Comment: Chris Stratton - Your question is a good one.  I was hoping the calculation method that someone offers as an answer to my question would address that factor as it is essential to have sufficient force to move the screen under the load to shake bits through the screen.  My gut feeling is that a 3/4 hp motor is WAY over kill for this application as I can manually shake such a screen & load just using my hands in the air or on a wooden frame that is suspended above a wheel barrow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a physics/mechancis question, not an electronics question. A suitable motor could be steam, internal combustion, horse-mill, water-mill, I could go on. The fact that the OP suggests an electric motor does not make the question about electronics.

Comment: @Brian Drummond - I'm aware.  My comment was in response to his comment--not his math.  The whole point of my question was to see someone else's math to compare to my own to determine how small of a motor I could use & more importantly--what type of motor I would need to use--which not being an EE I don't know.  That's why I asked the question here & not in the physic SE.  In general, I find the answers offered here to be much better than the Physics SE.

Comment: @Brian Drummond - No, it shouldn't have come across that way because I didn't indicate that fact because my mathematical methods for arriving at the motor HP are not as elegant as a proper physics approach to solving the problem-- which is why I didn't mention it.  The reason for the motor type is even more basic--I have more than one motor type, rpm, & hp motor to choose from & I don't want to use a universal motor when I should have used a brushed or an induction type motor.  Your assumptions to the contrary are unnecessarily imaginative.

Comment: Er, a universal motor *is* a brushed motor.  Generally speaking you want an induction motor for fixed machinery if you can tolerate the weight (which you are going to need anyway to stabilize this contraption), and your desire for belt drive is commonly associated with those too.  You'd use a brushed universal motor if you wanted to make it hand held, or wanted to speed control it without the complication of a vector drive, and didn't mind a lot of motor noise along with the obvious mechanism noise.

Comment: Ok.  My only concern about the universal motors that I have (previously used in vacuum cleaners) is that they have a very high rpm & I don't know what their rpm would be under loaded & unloaded conditions.  Alternatively, I have a .5 hp, 1100 rpm motor from an old AC unit that may be a better choice.  Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the soil is a solid mass that is stuck to and moves with the tray, that's an upper bound for the moving mass, of about 9kg.

If the soil is a solid mass which slides frictionlessly over the tray, that is a lower bound for the moving mass, of about 2kg.

Unfortunately, in neither case is any work done on the soil, so the power needed is zero, plus losses.

Maybe that's the wrong tack. The movement of the soil could be a really horrible thing to compute. Let's do the physicist thang and take an upper bound. Let's assume a motor that runs at constant speed, and provides whatever force the shaker system loads it with. Then calculate the maximum instantaneous power as peak force * speed.

The 'stuck to the tray' bound provides an upper bound for force, as when the soil slips, to be 'eaten' by the grid, the force required to accelerate it will be less. So we will go with the 9kg moving mass.

For 6" = 150mm peak to peak motion, r = 0.075m amplitude, at 132 cycles/minute = 2.2Hz, \$\omega\$= 14 rad/second, the approximate equation of motion for a tray driven by a crank is

\$ y = r\sin(\omega t)\$

the speed is \$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = -r\omega\cos(\omega t)\$

and the acceleration is \$\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2} =  -r\omega^2\sin(\omega t)\$

Substituting back, we get the peak speed to be about 1m/s, and the peak acceleration to be 14m/\$s^2\$. With a moving mass of 9kg, that means a peak accelerating force of 132N, or about 132 watts for the product of peak speed and peak force.

So, with a constant speed motor (which is probably a reasonable assumption for a 'large' motor running at high speed, geared down, so a good energy storage flywheel effect), the power peaks taken from it will be 132 watts, or about 1/5th HP in the (furlong, cwt, fortnight) system of units. The mean power will therefore be less.

Remember this is an upper bound, the actual power required for real soil will be less again. Perhaps if you assumed a solid mass of soil, with a friction coefficient to the tray. Set up the equation of motion for soil and tray as a function of friction. Compute actual power required, then differentiate with respect to friction to find the maximum power. But then again, it might just be easier to use the 1/5th HP motor. Perhaps an air motor would be ideal, from an industrial air-powered nut driver, it might even be geared down to the right speed. A horse-mill would probably be impractical, with the horse feed an all. An electric motor is certainly an option.

Look up 'pumpjack' on wikipedia, to see how the motor used for that application is a high slip type, so that energy can be delivered from the flywheel during the period of high loading.

Comment: I still think this forum is the best place for my question as an EE would have superior knowledge about motors & the application of them--more so than a Physicist would, imo. I also consider the responses from the helpful people in this forum to be much better than those that I've received in the Physics forum. Perhaps being required to apply physics for practical purposes rather than theoretical ones makes for a more proficient & helpful individual?